# Lookups in for single PostgreSQL table suddenly extremely slow after large update

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I have a `messages` table with a few million records in it. My Rails app includes a query on most pages to count the number of unread `messages` to show the user. This query - and all queries of the `messages` table - is unchanged and was working fine until yesterday.

Yesterday, I created a new `messages` column and ran [`update_all`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) to update the new column on each of my few million `messages` records. Simple enough, and I've done this plenty of times before, albeit on a smaller number of records.

However, now every query to COUNT or SELECT `messages` takes 30+ seconds to return. Before the migration and `update_all`, it was only taking 100ms or so to do the COUNTs or SELECTs.

I've tried a number of things, but the queries remain super slow. I've tried to `REINDEX messages` and I've tried to `VACCUM messages` but neither helped significantly.

The rest of the database tables remain working as usual, but this issue with the `messages` table is keeping everything running at a crawl. Does anyone have any ideas about why this happening, and what else I can try to fix it?

Comment: Hard to tell for sure without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried to `REINDEX` messages and I've tried to `VACCUM messages` but neither helped significantly.

You missed the important [`ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html). Possibly in the form of `VACUUM ANALYZE`. (Typically `autovacuum` should take care of this, though!)

Updating all rows creates as many dead tuples in the physical relation. To free up space, it might be the rare occasion for a

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE messages;
```

Takes an exclusive lock on the table! And since you run counts *per user* a lot, you might as well use [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html):

```
CLUSTER messages USING that_index_sorting_by_user_id_and_the_read_flag
```

For fast counts per user, that appropriate (multicolumn) index is key either way. Depends on undisclosed schema & queries.

Al that said, you shouldn't see such a dramatic drop in performance. Maybe you exhausted a resource. Like, just not enough RAM to keep the bigger indexes cached.